# How to run same test case in different browsers in Cucumber using Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, cross-browser-testing

New to automation and Cucumber.

I have a .feature test case (a simple login function) that I would like to run in multiple browsers in parallel.

I want to store the browser properties in a global property file and then be able to use this in my runner class.

Any suggestion on how to implement this would be helpful!!!

P.S: Using JUnit for my unit testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263077/how-to-test-multiple-browserversions-with-selenium-and-junit